# Как сделать динамичный расчёт ширины блока на jQuery?

Tags: jquery, resize, width

Хочу сделать, чтобы ширина блока и значение offset рассчитывались динамично, а не были статичны. Я так понимаю, что нужно использовать resize, но не пойму, как его можно внедрить.
Вот что у меня получилось:

```
$(function(){
    var exp = $("#tile_shop2");
    var expB = exp.width();
    var expW = $(window).width();

    var offset = exp.offset();
    exp.css("margin-left", -((expB-expW)/2+offset.left));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    resize();
    $(window).on("resize", resize);
});
function resize(){
    var exp = $("#tile_shop2");
    var expB = exp.width();
    var expW = $(window).width();

    var offset = exp.offset();
    exp.css("margin-left", -((expB-expW)/2+offset.left));
}
```

Comment: Вынесли бы вы это выражение в отдельную функцию, хотя бы...

Comment: Этим и занимался, случайно отправил. Спасибо)